# Android layout switching

Tags: java, android

I've a simple problem.I'm trying to switch layout between Main Menu and About pages.In Main Menu, there is no problem when i click the "about" button.But in "about" layout, when i click "return to menu" button it just doesn't work.and the code of that layout is in about.java, which also extends Activity.Please have a look.

in MainActivity.java:

```
Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), About.class);
                 setContentView(R.layout.about);
            }
        });
```

works just fine.But in About.java:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);


         }

    });
```

nothing happens.I tried every combination of inside onClick() but just doesn't work.What are your ideas?Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: can you remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in About.java and try?

Comment: wow realy strange code. You're missing some realy important part of how Android works. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html
What you're trying to do is just to open differents Activities (I guess), so startActivity is the right part. Everything else is realy bad, see http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#follow-field-naming-conventions

Comment: You should look into fragments vs. activities.  This sounds like a good case for using fragments if you're just swapping out the views instead of switching activities completely.

Comment: so, on MainActivity click replace `setContentView` call with a `startActivity(intent);` call. On About activity just call finish(); on clicking the button. Bonus: set About as a child activity of MainActivity and provide up navigation

Answer (score 1):

In Main Activity,java, it's not starting any activity, it's basically just changing the view. It seems to be working but actually it's not.

You should declare the intent and then call the start activity method. The other activity should have a method onCreate where you can set the content view (using the method setContentView).

It should be something like this:

MainActivity.java

```
Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), About.class);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

About.java

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
     }

});
```

For more information, check this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the same like in your MainActivity in your AboutActivity:

```
button1_.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  //should be without this line if you set the layout in your onCreate method in the MainActivity (respectively AboutActivity)
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

If it works once, should work twice as well

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` will be called in MainActivity.onCreate() right? why should we explicitly call that?

Comment: it's not necessary I think, when we create the intent and then start the activity it is enough, but the guy set it and I think it won't make the things worst, so I left it there, but else the right way is without it -> Documentation http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: what's the purpose of setting the contentView before starting an Activity ?

Comment: setContentView() sets the layout before to start the new activity. Documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: I know what setContentView does, but whats the purpose of setting the contentView before the Activity Start ?  normally we call setContentView in the Activity